# CATransition Lag on Older Devices

Tags: iphone, catransition

I am developing an application that uses CATransition to improve the transition effects between different subviews on a view controller. The transitions work very well when I am testing them on my iPod Touch 4G, there is no visible sign of any issues. However, when I test this on my iPod Touch 2G, there is significant lag when changing subviews using CATransition. However, to my knowledge this lag has never caused a crash.

I'm wondering if there's any way to fix this lag for older devices. I have looked around on multiple websites, and it seems that not one has mentioned this problem on older devices. Is there anything I can do with the code to try and fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WWDC 2010 videos are not working at the moment, but I just watched a great video earlier this week entitled "Performance Analysis with Instruments". Couple that with the double videos with "Core Animation in Practice" and it should give you a lot of pointers on what might be going on that's causing such a performance drag.  They go over many scenarios that cause dropped framerates and strategies on overcoming them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain how exactly I should use Instruments to analyze the performance of the application? I am a relatively newbie developer, and haven't used the tool before.